# How do I pick a sub-element in Yahoo Pipes?

Tags: select, element, pipe, yahoo, yahoo-pipes

Below is an example of the type of RSS structure I am trying to parse (it is not complete for ease of explanation):

```
<rss>
  <item>
    <span>
      <a href="test.html">test</a>
      <a href="test2.html">test 2</a>
    </span>
  </item>
  <item>
    <span>
      <a href="test3.html">test 3</a>
      <a href="test4.html">test 4</a>
    </span>
  </item>
</rss>
```

I have used the XPath Fetch Page module to fetch the page and used "//body/item" to select all the different item's.

My question is how do I select the second  tag in the structure?

I can select the first  tag by using something like **item.span.a.content** in Yahoo Pipes which would return "*test*" and "*test 3*" for the above example.

I want "*test 2*" and "*test 4*" to be returned.  I thought that I could use something like **item.span.a[1].content** or **item.span.a{1}.content** but this does not seem to work.

I hope this is understandable I found it hard to explain.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to use: item.span.1.a.content

where 1 was the element in the a list that I needed.